# still broadcasting to destroyed controller scope angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive, its callback looks like this:

```
function Callback(){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'somePath',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, el) {
        scope.cancel = function(){
          el.remove()
          scope.$destroy()
        }
      },
      controller: 'someController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
  }
```

The link method just adds a cancel method that removes the directive from the DOM.

In the directive controller I'm listening for an event:

```
$rootScope.$on('parent', function(){
  someService.addToArray(someData)
})
```

This method just pushes data to an array.

In a parent controller and view, where this directive is being leveraged I'm actually firing the broadcast. Part of the parent controller:

```
var vm = this
vm.broadcastEvent = broadcastEvent      
function broadcastEvent(){
  $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent', 'someData')
}
```

And in the view I have some clickable div that fires this method.

It works great, the directive hears the broadcast and adds data to an array before I remove the element and destroy the scope.

The problem is, after i invoke `.cancel`, the element gets removed and presumably the scope is destroyed, but it still adds data to the array. Am I missing something about how `scope.$destroy()` works?

I can get the behavior I want, by deregistering the `$on`, do I just need to do this either way? I guess the question is, does destroying the controller scope negate any `$on` defined within it, or do you need to make sure you explicitly deregister before destroying the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener function is registered on $rootScope and will survive after the directive $scope is destroyed:

```
$rootScope.$on('parent', function listener(){
  someService.addToArray(someData)
})
```

That controller needs to save the deregister function returned by the call to the $rootScope.$on method:

```
this.deregister = $rootScope.$on('parent', function listener(){
  someService.addToArray(someData)
})
```

The cancel function needs to invoke the de-registration function:

```
  link: function(scope, el) {
    scope.cancel = function(){
      el.remove()
      scope.$destroy()
      scope.vm.deregister()
    }
  },
  controller: 'someController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
```

---

> shouldn't the deregister happen before the scope is destroyed?

It doesn't matter. As you discovered, because the listener is registered on $rootScope it is stored on an array on $rootScope (specifically `$rootScope.$$listeners`). It is removed from `$rootScope.$$listeners` by invoking the de-registration function.

It is the nature of object-oriented runtimes such a JavaScript, that an object is only removed from memory (garbage collected) when all references to them are are destroyed. Since a reference to the listener function is stored on $rootScope, it (and its execution context) survives.

If the listener had been registered on the directive $scope, it would have been automatically de-registered when the scope was destroyed.

Comment: yep, this is exactly what I ended up doing, and it made more sense as I was writing the question. Thanks as always @georgeawg!

Comment: shouldn't the deregister happen before the scope is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the `scope.$destroy()` is called properly.

As it's wrote in the [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) doc :

> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent
>   scope.   [...]  Note that, in AngularJS, there is also a $destroy jQuery
>   event, which can be used to clean up DOM bindings before an element is
>   removed from the DOM.

So, I think you should do it like :

```
link: function(scope, el) {
        el.on('$destroy', function() {
          scope.$destroy();
        });

        scope.cancel = function(){
          el.remove();
        }
      }
```

Tell me if it solves your problem